# Can server side logic be added to firebase to implement an automatically incremental key?

Tags: ios, firebase

I am new to firebase, and I am trying to implement an iOS chat app. I am wondering if there is a way to add a incremental id to the received message.

For example:
I send the following message to firebase

```
 {date:  "2015-10-14T04:30:43", name: "Jacob" text:"Hi"  userId: "y8jFdNwRAX" }
```

Is that possible that firebase add a messageId key to it

```
 {msgId:1, date:  "2015-10-14T04:30:43", name: "Jacob" text:"Hi"  userId: "y8jFdNwRAX"};
```

and if I send another msg, firebase add msgId and increase it by 1:

```
 {msgId:2, date:  "2015-10-14T04:31:40", name: "Jacob" text:"morning"  userId: "y8jFdNwRAX"};
```

Not sure if firebase can do this or not? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The answer is kind-of. But, what function does the msgId serve? If you are doing some kind of ordering, the date stamp could be used for that. You could also implement an increment in code (there's about 100 ways to do that) by storing a value within the child node. Or even a separate node that stores the value and can be incremented when you add a post.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Server side logic?

Comment: Nope. But doing an increment like that is a bad idea, no matter if you do it client-side or server-side. `push()` exists for a reason and the reasoning is explained in the docs.

Comment: @Jay Your comment is way more helpful though. If you turn it into an answer, it'll get my upvote.

Comment: @Jay, the msgId is used to save in the chat group, and to indicate any msgs with msgId large than that one will be unread. The chat group always keeps the last read msgId.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen,  I am new to firebase, and not sure if you can do the server side logic in firebase. You said "Yes it can", do you really mean it? or just randomly point to firebase.com/docs/ios?

Answer (score 6):

So the answer to the question is no, it's not going to happen with some kind of automated server side logic. And, that's a bad idea in general.

There are ways to emulate a counter but it can be really tricky to work with and there are so many ways it can go wrong, it's just not good code.

So I would suggest looking for another solution:

Perhaps for each message has a child node that tracks whether it's been read?

```
message_id_1
  timestamp: "2015-10-14T04:30:43"
  name: "Jacob"
  text: "Hi"
  userId: "y8jFdNwRAX"
  read: "yes"
message_id_2
  timestamp: "2015-10-14T04:30:50"
  name: "Bob"
  text: "Hi Back At Ya"
  userId: "y9jaksjk"
  read: "no"
```

You could even have a 'read' node and an 'unread' node

```
read_messages
     message_id_1
      timestamp: "2015-10-14T04:30:43"
      name: "Jacob"
      text: "Hi"
      userId: "y8jFdNwRAX"

unread_messages
      message_id_2
        timestamp: "2015-10-14T04:30:50"
        name: "Bob"
        text: "Hi Back At Ya"
        userId: "y9jaksjk"
```

And here's a tricky one: Store messages in their own node and a reference to those unread ones in the users node

```
all_messages
 message_id_1
  timestamp: "2015-10-14T04:30:43"
  from_userId: "y9jaksjk"
  text: "This is message 1"
 message_id_2
  timestamp: "2015-10-14T04:30:50"
  from_userId: "y9jaksjk"
  text: "this is message 2"

users
  "y8jFdNwRAX"
     my_unread_messages:
       message_id_1: true
```

(message_id_1: true saved as a child of the user is a reference that indicates the message is for that user and has not been read. When read, remove the reference.)

All of this is conjecture as we don't know the scope of the app and the use of the messages.

You may want to visit the docs a bit more and review some of the sample code provided for other options.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jay. I was thinking to add "read" key in the message, but it will need multiple copies of the message if this is a group chat. So that's why I prefer a ordered message Id. Can I assume it's impossible to implement server logic in Firebase? Because I didn't find such examples so far.

Comment: That's generally correct. Even if it was available the other methods presented may be better solutions. While you can make multiple copies of the message (data duplication is A-OK in firebase) you may want to think about other solutions: maybe a 'unread_messages' child node within the user node that contains references the messages that user has not read. Once read, remove the message_id from he node - similar to the last example above.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say the answer is no. It can, in fact, be done client-side with security rules:  http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/xLq7grcc/ It's still not the best plan and typically solves the wrong problem. Push IDs are generally a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same question. I used timestamp as sort of "messageId" in server side to track the order(Probably not a good idea, but it solves what I need), and you can create '.indexon' on this "messageId" in the security rules to get better performance.

Here is an example for the security rule:

```
{
"rules": {
    "Messages":{           
        "$Message":{
            ".indexOn": "messageId"
          }
     }
}
```

setup code in iOS:

```
msg[@"messageId"] = kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp;
```

Note, there is a possible bug for Firebase: the one you received timestamp from FEventTypeChildAdded seems different with the one saved in Firebase DB sometimes(a couple hundred ms diff).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem for another reason

incremented keys can be achieved by transactions:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#firebase_runTransactionBlock

an example for swift:

```
let messagesRef = ...
let counterRef = ... //you need to keep the count of messages
counterRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData) -> FTransactionResult! in
        var value = currentData.value as? Int
        if (value == nil) {value=0}
        currentData.value = value! + 1
        return FTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
        }) { (error, commited, snap) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            }
            if commited {
                //if increment is made set message
                let messageInfo = .... 
                messagesRef.childByAppendingPath(snap.value).setValue(messageInfo)
    }
```

if the only goal is ordering, childbyautoid function would be enough since it creates the keys accordingly

```
messagesRef.childByAutoId().setValue(messageInfo)
```

hope this helps someone